# Z-indexing and Css Floats possible to do in masonry?

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, jquery-masonry

I have maosnry installed on my website. I am trying to make it look like this http://christelwinther.dk/

Do you know if this is possible to do? I am guessing i ened to use CSS floats or z-indexing but not sure.

ANy help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That site is using absolute positioning of it's image elements not a JavaScript/jQuery plugin/library like Masonry to position elements.  If you want to position elements like that I don't see how Masonry would help you achieve that.